# AS3: Extending default ScrollBar component

Tags: flash, combobox, components, scrollbar, actionscript-3

I'd like to adjust the width of the default ScrollBar that appears inside of a Flash ComboBox.  From my research on various forums, it seems like the best approach would be to subclass fl.controls.ScrollBar, which I've tried doing here:

```
package helpers {

  import fl.controls.ScrollBar;

  public class CustomScroller extends fl.controls.ScrollBar {

    public function CustomScroller() {
      super();
      trace("custom scroller in full effect!");
      width = 40;
    }  
  }
}
```

Then, in my library, I've taken the "ScrollBar" movie clip that appears upon initial creation of a ComboBox and changed the base class to "helpers.CustomScroller".  I've got three ComboBox instances on the stage; however, none of them are showing anything but the default width, nor am I seeing the output from the `trace()` statement in my constructor.

Any idea why this isn't working?  Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only had to do this once, and don't want to do it any more.  Basically, to accomplish this, I needed to create a copy of fl.controls.ScrollBar called fl.controls.WideScrollBar.  You also need to modify fl.containers.BaseScrollPane and fl.containers.ScrollPane.

In WideScrollBar I overrode `public static const WIDTH:Number`

In WideBaseScrollPane you need to change the class of _verticalScrollBar and/or _horizontalScrollBar to be WideScrollBar.  Then in my WideScrollPane, I overrode the calls to setStyle in the contructor to point to my custom class instances for skinning.

Comment: Thanks!  Sounds like a PITA but I don't have time to write my own classes right now.  Where did you find the source for the components themselves in order to modify them?

Answer (score 1):

Add the scroll pane as a child to a Sprite, then scale that parent sprite.  Scroll bars will adjust accordingly.  If source of ScrollPane is now too big, scale by inverse of same scale factor.